# Problem retrieving individual objects in pickled dictionary (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, object, pickle, continue

My program stores "food" objects that are pickled into a dictionary and stored in a csv file, which acts as a database. I want to retrieve individual food objects on command from the dictionary, but when I attempt to I seem to only retrieve the last object in the dictionary.

```
import pickle

class Food(object):
  fooddict = dict({})

  def __init__(self, name, weight, calories, time):
    self.name = name
    self.weight = weight
    self.calories = calories
    self.time = time

  def __str__(self):
    return '{self.name}s'.format(self=self) + \
           ' weigh {self.weight}'.format(self=self) + \
           ' ounces, contain {self.calories}'.format(self=self) + \
           ' calories, and stay fresh for {self.time}'.format(self=self) + \
           ' days.'

  @classmethod
  def createFoodInput(cls):
    name = str(input("Enter the name: "))
    weight = float(input("Enter the weight: "))
    calories = float(input("Enter the calories: "))
    time = float(input("Enter how many days it can store for: "))
    return cls(name, weight, calories, time)

  def storeFoodDict(f):
    fooddict = Food.retreiveFoodDict()
    if fooddict == "Empty File":
        fooddict = dict({f.name: f})
        with open("food.csv", 'wb') as filewriter:
            try:
                pickle.dump(fooddict, filewriter)
            except:
                print("Error storing pickled dictionary")
    else:
        food_found = False
        for key in list(fooddict):
            if key.__eq__(f.name):
                print("Food already stored!")
                food_found = True
        if not food_found:
            fooddict.update({f.name: f})
            with open("food.csv", 'wb') as filewriter:
                try:
                    pickle.dump(fooddict, filewriter)
                except:
                    print("Error storing pickled dictionary")
  @classmethod
  def retreiveFoodDict(cls):
    with open("food.csv", 'rb') as filereader:
        try:
            fooddict = pickle.load(filereader)
            return fooddict
        except EOFError:
            return("Empty File")

def findFood(title):
fooddict = Food.retreiveFoodDict()
for key in list(fooddict):
   if key.__eq__(title):
        continue
return fooddict[key]

s = "apple"
n = findFood(s)           #does not work, it returns banana instead of apple
                          #which is really just grabbing whatever is the 
                          #last object in the dictionary

m = findFood("banana")    #seems to work, but only because banana is the
                          #last object in the dictionary

print(n) #should print an apple "food object" but instead prints a banana

print(str(m.calories)) #works, but if I said n.calories it would still print
                       #m.calories instead
p = Food.retreiveFoodDict() #seems to work and retrieve the dictionary
print(str(p))               #also seems to work of course
```

Console Output:
bananas weigh 5.0 ounces, contain 120.0 calories, and stay fresh for 3.0 days.
120.0

{'apple': <**main**.Food object at 0x00D2C2E0>, 'banana': <**main**.Food object at 0x00D36D00>}

The dictionary contains 2 food objects (apple and banana), but the print(n) statement shows a banana, not an apple. Can anyone point out why this is or what I am misunderstanding? Thank you so much!

Comment: Why do you pickle and then put in csv, instead of just picking the whole thing?

Comment: Seems like the formatting of the class and the output got messed up, but you can [edit] to fix it. See [code formatting help](/editing-help#code) if you need it. BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. Also BTW you should make a [mre].

Comment: [Shelve](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html) your fruits!

Comment: What do you mean pickle the whole thing? I am trying to pickle the entire dictionary,  which is my database,  each time I store a new object in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own problem. I was misusing the continue in my findFood function.
This code solved my issues.

```
def getFood(food_name):
    fooddict = Food.retreiveFoodDict()
        for key in list(fooddict):
           if key.__eq__(food_name):
               return fooddict[key]
```

What this function does is simply retrieve a dictionary of objects in a csv file and iterates through the keys until the passed key name is located. If found, the proper key name will be returned as a food object. My original mistake was using the "continue" keyword to stop the for-loop, which was returning the object directly after the one we wanted.